# Find out whether a template file is used by a page and get that page -Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I'm developing now a wordpress theme, and wondering if there is an option to know if a template file is being used by a page?
I need the link to that page...
thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function **get_page_template_slug( $post_id )** will return the slug of the currently assigned page template (or an empty string if no template has been assigned - or false if the $post_id does not correspond to an actual page). You can easily use this anywhere (in The Loop, or outside) to determine whether any page has been assigned a page template.

is_page_template(); function will return true when template is used. you can also pass file name to check if particular template is applied or not.

```
if ( is_page_template('about.php') ) {
// Returns true when 'about.php' is being used.
} else {
// Returns false when 'about.php' is not being used.
}
```

There is one more method too. You can use get_post_meta to get value of applied template.

```
global $post;
get_post_meta($post->ID,'_wp_page_template',true);
```

Comment: I have the same problem but and i try this and not working

Answer (score 5):

The previously suggested answer will not get you what you want. It will just show you in the current page or a page you specify is using the template not find any pages that are using it.

If you want to actually search to see if any pages are using a template you can make a query. meta_query isn't the most efficient/fastest but depending on what you are building probably won't be an issue.

```
$query = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'post_type'   => 'page',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'meta_query'  => array(
                        array(
                            'key'   => '_wp_page_template',
                            'value' => 'your-template.php',
                        ),
                    ),
                )
            );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    /* There is a match so either start the loop and use get_the_permalink() to get the link or make a foreach loop and get the ids of the items and get_the_permalink($id) */
}
```